# Pandas groupby and sum according to an index date from two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, pandas-groupby

I wanted to groupby and sum the features according to the index date from 2 separate data frames.

What I mean by that is, let us suppose I have the following data frame:

| MemberID | indexDate | yValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-11-02 | 2 |
| a | 2019-02-03 | 3 |
| b | 2018-02-03 | 2 |
| a | 2020-02-03 | 9 |

Now, initially, I created another row with the look-up date (the time period where I want to sum the features from) with the following code:

```
df['lookupDate'] = df['indexDate'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

And the following data frame was obtained:

| MemberID | indexDate | lookupDate | yValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-11-02 | 2019-11-02 | 2 |
| a | 2019-02-03 | 2018-02-03 | 3 |
| b | 2018-02-03 | 2017-02-03 | 2 |
| a | 2020-02-03 | 2019-02-03 | 9 |

I have another data frame that has feature values that I want to merge with the above data frame. The feature data frame looks something like this:

| MemberID | serviceDate | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-09-02 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| a | 2019-03-03 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2018-05-03 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| a | 2020-06-03 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Now, I want to merge such that, I am able to look at each row of the first data frame and consider the lookupDate as the cycle-start-date and the indexDate as the cycle-end-date for the second data frame.

By this, I mean that for MemberID, 'a', for the first data frame, the cycle-start-date would be '2019-11-02' and the cycle-end-date would be '2020-11-02'. Now, using this I will look into the second data frame and groupby MemberID and sum up the features for MemberID, 'a', such that it is groupby and summed up within the cycle-start and cycle-end date.

Here, from the second data frame, the first and the last row for MemberID 'a' would be selected because the serviceDate lies between '2019-11-02' and '2020-11-02'. So, for the first row of the first data frame I want a result like:

| MemberID | indexDate | lookupDate | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | yValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-11-02 | 2019-11-02 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

Now, I want to do this for each row with a different cycle-start and cycle-end dates.

Comment: Why is `yValue=2` and not `yValue=4` in output?

Comment: Only the features from the feature data frame is being added. There are 2 data frames so the initial one doesn't change while the other one is being summed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df2 = df1.merge(df, on='MemberID', how='outer')

df2 = df1.merge(df, on='MemberID', how='outer')

df2 = (df2[df2['serviceDate'].between(df2['lookupDate'], df2['indexDate'])]
          .groupby(['MemberID','indexDate','lookupDate','yValue'], as_index=False).sum())
df2['yValue'] = df2.pop('yValue')
print (df2)
  MemberID  indexDate lookupDate  feature1  feature2  feature3  yValue
0        a 2020-02-03 2019-02-03         0         1         1       9
1        a 2020-11-02 2019-11-02         2         1         0       2
```